# Is it possible to cache an api response to make the api available offline?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, browser-cache

I have an api for master date, i want to cache it so that when i go offline and still call the api, the response is available.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you have to make request first before going offline

Comment: @Justinas yes that will be called first, but how it can be done, is there any other way then service workers?

Comment: Write response to localStorage. Use it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the use of "service workers". It allows you to do api response caching for offline mode.

Here is the official documentation for it : [Angular Service Worker Intro](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro).

They are plenty of tutorials on the internet. Follow one of them for your particular use case.

Hope it helps!